# Flash Action Script

Tags: jquery, actionscript, click, clipboard

I want to write an application in action script.

The application will appended with jQuery to the page and if it is appended, copy it immediately to the system clipboard. I have this code:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#obsah').append('<object width="100" height="100" id="copysw" align="middle"><param name="movie" value="cp.swf" /><PARAM NAME=FlashVars VALUE="hodnota=something"></object>');
});
```

And Action Script

```
 but.onRelease = function() {
    System.setClipboard(hodnota);
 };
 but.onRelease();
```

But it's not working. I still must click on a flash window to do this operation. I also trying click on a flash via jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#obsah').append('<object width="100" height="100" id="copysw" align="middle"><param name="movie" value="cp.swf" /><PARAM NAME=FlashVars VALUE="hodnota=something"></object>');
$('#copysw').click();
});
```

But nothing worked for me. Please give me some tips how to do this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should check this link [ZeroClipBoard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/) for learning how to copy to clipboard.

Although it is limited,for good reasons, to only copy when the user trigger the action... such as click.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I checked this before a start doing this.But it didn't work as i wont. I combined this with jquery context menu plugin [link](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/vs-contextmenu) I tried give the ZeroClipBoard to one element in context menu but didn't worked.